# Meld, pygtk on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, pip, meld

I am trying to install meld on Mac OSX, I used macports and installed meld and pygtk, but when I run it this is what I get

```
$ meld
Couldn't bind the translation domain. Some translations won't work.
'module' object has no attribute 'bindtextdomain'
Cannot import: pygtk
No module named pygtk
```

So I tried to use pip to get pygtk

```
$ pip install pygtk
Downloading/unpacking pygtk
Downloading pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2 (2.4MB): 2.4MB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package pygtk
********************************************************************
* Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
* To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
********************************************************************
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
********************************************************************
```

`* Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *`

`* To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *`

```
********************************************************************

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/0y/8w4qlr0d6tv6_jgk87x53fcw0000gn/T/pip_build_frazras/pygtk
```

I am not sure what is causing that error or what else to do, I would appreciate some direction as to what steps to try next.

Comment: `only supported on windows` means Microsoft Windows. Download `pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2`, unpack it and `read the INSTALL file`.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to build a native port. Just download the dmg file and install it as you would with any Mac app.

Here it is: https://github.com/yousseb/meld/releases/tag/osx-v1

Hope you guys find it useful...

Comment: I use this package and it works nice ^. Also here you have other options https://gist.github.com/p1nox/6102015

Answer (score 1):

reinstalling all meld dependencies works for me.

```
brew rm --force gobject-introspection pygobject py2cairo pygtk rarian meld
brew cask install meld
```

Comment: Worked great for me in April 2019 to fix a broken Mac OSX dmg installation